# Как правильно записывать данные в Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

У меня есть метод в котором записываю данные в `Realm`:

```
public void setChatsList(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {
    Realm realm = null;

    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chatsModel);
            }
        });

    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

А считываю данные из базы в этом методе:

```
ChatsModel getAllChatsList() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<ChatsModel> chatsModelResult = realm.where(ChatsModel.class).findAll();

    ChatsModel chatsModel = chatsModelResult.get(0);

    return chatsModel;
}
```

Класс ChatsModel:

```
public class ChatsModel extends RealmObject {

    public ChatsModel() {
    }

    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    private Response response;

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Класс Response:

```
public class Response extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private Integer count;
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<Item> items = null;

//Сеттеры и геттеры
}
```

Когда использую метод **copyToRealmOrUpdate()** для записи в базу, то он не сохраняет. То есть при получении данных в методе `getAllChatsList()` возвращает 0.

А когда записываю с помощью метода **insertOrUpdate()**, то он каждый раз при записи не обновляет уже существующую запись а записывает рядом с предыдущим. То есть даже если одинаковые данные

Вопрос: Как можно решить проблему записи и чтения?

Comment: что за Real ?) обьясни в кратце

Comment: =). Realm — кросс-платформенная мобильная база данных для iOS (доступная в Swift & Objective-C) и Android.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял ничего из вопроса

Comment: NO sql?или простая?

Comment: @elik с каких пор sql — простая? Если вы с ней даже не знакомы, зачем вам эта информация?

Comment: NOSQL).........

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, прошу перечитать, максимально пытался объяснить детально)

Comment: DevOma понятно спасибо)у меня целых 3 проекта на но ске)не люблю яя её)лучше всех и вся ораккккл)жаль не обьяснить заказчику)

Answer (score 6):

Когда Вы используете `copyToRealmOrUpdate` в Вашей модели `ChatsModel` должно быть поле с первичным ключом, т.е. поле, которое является уникальным и помечается аннотацией `@PrimaryKey`. При записи новых данных в базу если поле с первичным ключом будет отличным от тех , которые уже храняться в бд, то создастся новая запись, а если первичный ключ будет совпадать с каким-нибудь другим первичным ключом существующей записи, то запись просто обновиться.

**UPDATE**

Можете изменить Вашу модель следующим образом:

```
public class ChatsModel extends RealmObject {

public ChatsModel() {
}

@PrimaryKey
private int id;
@SerializedName("response")
@Expose
private Response response;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Response response) {
    this.response = response;
} 

}
```

Перед сохранением в бд id должен быть уникальным, тогда будет создана новая запись. Если, например, в бд есть три записи и у первой id = 1, у второй  id = 2, у третьей id = 3, и при сохранении новый id будет совпадать с каким-нибудь id уже существующей записи, то запись просто обновится.

`@PrimaryKey`  используется совместно с методом сохранения `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate()`, когда нам нужно обновить какие-то поля уже существующей записи или сохранить новую.

Если Вам не нужно обновлять записи, а просто сохранять все подряд, также можете использовать метод `realm.copyToRealm()` в этом случае id не нужен и поле не надо отмечать аннотацией `@PrimaryKey`, этот метод сохраняет все записи подряд не используя первичный ключ, даже если есть одинаковые записи.

Comment: `При записи новых данных в базу если поле с первичным ключом будет отличным от тех , которые уже храняться в бд` - Не совсем понятно, при записи новых данных у меня же отсутствует первичный ключ

Comment: @DevOma добавьте в вопрос Вашу модель - ChatsModel, попробую объяснить на ее примере, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: обновил вопрос...